# Error in MATLAB/polymath code modeling packed bed reactor

Tags: matlab, ode

I am designing a reactor for steam reforming the first step to NH<sub>3</sub> synthesis. I am using polymath. Can someone help me get rid of the errors?

[image: these are the messages]

This is the polymath code:

```
d(FCH4) / d(W) = rCH4 
FCH4(0) = 606.44
d(FH2O) / d(W) = rH2O 
FH2O(0) = 766.041
d(FH2) / d(W) = rH2 
FH2(0) = 0
d(FCO) / d(W) = rCO 
FCO(0) = 0
d(p)/d(W) = (-alpha/(2*p))*(FT/FT0)
FT0=606.44+766.041
rH2O(0)=0
rCO(0)=0
rH2(0)=0
FT=FCO+FH2+FH2O+FCH4
rCH4=-rCO
rCO=-rH2O
rH2O=1/3*rH2
P=3550
P0=100
p=P/P0  
xH2O=FH2O/FT
xCO=FCO/FT
xCH4=FCH4/FT
xH2=FH2/FT
T=1093
Kp=1.198e17*exp(-26830/T)
k1=310.8e7 
KCO=4.013e2
KH=1e2
KH2O=0.90194
PH2=xH2*P
PCO=xCO*P
PCH4=xCH4*P
W(0) = 0
PH2O=xH2O*P
density0=1.521
Ac=0.0113097
densitycat=1123.6
por=0.45
gc=1
G=207708.33
Dp=0.000125
rCH4=((k1(PCH4*PH2O^0.5)/PH2^1.25)(1-((PCO*PH2^3)/Kp*PCH4*PH2O))/(1+KCO*PCO+KH*PH2^0.5+KH2O(PH2O/PH2))^2
Beta0 = (((G*(1-por))/(density0*gc*Dp*(por^3)))*(1.75*G)) * (1e-5)
alpha = (2*Beta0)/(Ac*densitycat*(1-por)*P0)
W(f)=24943.92
```